# Testing Free Will

Tags: free-will, computation

Could we ever come up with an experiment that is able to explain once and for all if free will exists or not?  Another way to put it: given a universe and agents acting within it, is it possible for such agents to determine whether or not they possess free will?  The more I think about this problem the more it seems undecidable to me, it seems structurally similar to the halting problem.

Comment: You cannot devise an experiment to prove free will because free will is itself an assumption of experimentation. The observation must break a causal identity between observer and observed, allowing for an "independent" judgement of outcomes. Besides, free will is indicated in the very idea that there is no "once and for all" in science. From an entirely different angle, I have always thought that a reasonably good "demonstration" of free will is observed in those protesting monks of Vietnam who sat calmly while burning alive.  Free will is an a priori condition of "being human."

Comment: I might add (above the agreement with the above comment) that the very setup "agents _within_ universe asking if they are free against it" is problematic. An agent to be able to put such question must not be a part or element of the universe. Although finding itself inside some world or reality, it should be something different from it "from the beginning", to be able to ask if it is free. Natural science thus simply cannot generate questions about "free will".

Comment: @ttnphns: this just your opinion. Why would it be impossible to be determined to ask the question "am I free?"

Comment: @Nelson Alexander: free will is not in any way an assumption of experimentation. How is free will necessary in thinking "I will drop those 2 rocks to see if the bigger will fall faster ?" All that is necessary is a desire to understand how the world works, the assumption that it is deterministic, and a method. If anything, determinism is a necessary assumption to experimentation. Where does the idea that our mind is not determined by physics intervene is this scheme? Suicide is merely an hint that people can be determined to kill themselves.

Comment: @armand, Say, you thought the bigger rock falls faster. Then you suddenly doubt it, to the extent that you become self-determined to pick two rocks and climb upstairs to drop them, to check. What else has forced you to disconnect from the former belief - other than yourself? Read book on physics? But it is only information; the decision has been still yours. Your experiment (doubt-projection-effort-action) clearly was possible due to your ability to partly break free of a previous disposition.

Comment: @armand. I certainly admit, I must do a better job of clarifying what I mean. But you seem to have a very idealized view of "experimentation." And thus an overly positive view of "determinate" laws of physics, an old-fashioned Laplace Demon that cannot admit indeterminacy into even the "brain." I'll try to provide a better answer. But in the meantime, try to imagine how the laws of physics we have discovered would calculate the behavior of "all physicists." Your answer might be "we are getting there." but I think there we enter an infinite regress. I'll try to think out a better answer.

Comment: @Nelson Alexander: the laws of physics dont calculate a thing. This question does not make sense in the present state.

Comment: @ttnphns: "the decision has been still yours" if you assume decisions are "ours", you are begging the question by assuming free will in order to prove it. In order to doubt a preconception (for example "heavier -> faster") it is enough to observe that it does not explain a phenomenon (for example, "why does a sheet of paper fall faster if ragged in a ball ?"). People don't doubt established theories out of thin air, they doubt because they are determined by the observed flaws in the theory. As long as you don't eliminate this very reasonnable possibility, you don't have a case for free will.

Comment: @armand, Hey, to be able to recognize that a new evidence - which itself is just a line of some _positive_ facts - shatters the theory and thus the theory is "flawed", i.e. it is _deficient_, - individual freedom of decision (or free will, as some call it) is necessary. You don't understand it. (I will stop here now, to avoid "long discussion in comments", so pardon me if I didn' convince you.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have there been any proposed empirical tests for free will?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/43124/have-there-been-any-proposed-empirical-tests-for-free-will)

Comment: @ttnphns: just repeating it won't make a demonstration. All we need is a prediction and an observation that it is not matched by facts. No decision at all is involved, let alone a free, undetermined one. If I expect a certain result but another outcome is before my eyes, I have to conclude my expectation was bad. There is no choice here whatsoever.

Comment: Ted Chiang proposed a device that would prove free will doesn't exist... all you have to do is build one.  :) https://www.nature.com/articles/436150a

Answer (score 27):

> is it possible for such agents to determine whether or not they possess free will?

A precondition for answering this question is that the term "free will" is sufficiently well defined. IMHO, it is not, and the lack of adequate definition is the cause of much fruitless debate.

Since we do need a clear demarcation line between approval and rejection of a hypothesis, the lack of a definite, descriptive definition with empirically observable markers makes testing in the scientific sense impossible. Thus, the question/hypothesis is underdetermined and not scientifically answerable.

Comment: This does not answer the questions. Please use the comment section.

Comment: Yes, it answers the question. The answer is NO, it is not possible for a agent to determine the answer to the question of whether they have free will, because _that_ question is not well posed.

Comment: This might be an answer, but it's a pretty low quality one. If there isn't a single definition, surely there are some competing popular definitions out there, which can be individually addressed. Even if there were really no definitions, chances are that some well-known philosophers would've said something on the subject at some point, which can then be cited. [The Wikipedia article on free will](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_will) would not be as long if there were little more to say on the subject other than "there exists no adequate definition of free will".

Comment: @NotThatGuy.  1) The length of an exposition does not necessarily indicate that the subject matter has been understood with clarity. 2) Yes individual concepts may be individually addressed. At the end of the day, person A may give a valid account of some more precisely defined concept, and person B may object that although the account given by A is valid, it does not actually address "free will". The "free will" question will remain "open", or unsettled, because one cannot settle a question without consensus on meaning, and there is no such consensus w.r.t. "free will".

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Not sure how that addresses the low quality point. Say there is a question asking "How do you sort a list in [some programming language]" on Stack Overflow. If an answer were to say little more than "we can't answer that because the way to do it depends on the type of list", that would get downvoted to oblivion (although closing the question for being too broad/unclear may be reasonable). That answer could be improved by answering the question for different types of lists. Similarly, this answer could be improved by providing answers for different definitions of free will.

Comment: @NotThatGuy. Is there anything in my answer that you find incorrect? Misleading? Or is it merely that you don't find it "helpful", that you think the answer is of low quality? Or is there some other reason? Although _you_ may not find the answer helpful, that may say more about _you_, than it says about whether the answer can assist someone in achieving clarity of thought on the topic.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy If it were incorrect or misleading, I would've said as much. I've already posted 2 comments expanding on why I said it's low quality. But just to expand on that some more: you did the bare minimum to "answer" the question; you provided no references or further explanation to back up what you said and you didn't expand on it in the ways mentioned above. Sometimes 2 sentences is all that's needed to sufficiently answer a question, sometimes it's not, in which case it's usually low quality. Quality and how many people something helped are related, but not one and the same.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I was agreeing with you, until I read the other answers. This answer seems completely appropriate, given the topic.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Think of it another way; a question on [mathematics.se] asking how to solve [Hilbert's 23rd problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_twenty-third_problem) could have “that problem is not actually answerable, because it's far too vague” as an answer, yet it _wouldn't_ necessarily be closed as “too broad”.

Comment: I think that this answer is basically right. There are some definitions of free will according to which it has been falsified already (i.e. detailed experiments have shown that the microstructure of the world has no spare degree of freedom that could be a nexus for causation by some force not described in the standard model + gravity). But there are plenty of compatibilist senses of free will according to which it is not falsifiable by any experiment.

Comment: I agree with the answerer. This topic is like many others. Clearly define your terms and it becomes trivial. It's all pointless though, because all people really want is to be able to *feel* like they have "free will" (how it's defined doesn't matter, because it invokes a certain emotional response regardless). We KNOW (roughly) how the universe works, which contains our brain, so as far as predicting observable phenomena, the free will debate doesn't change anything, it only changes the labels we use to describe things. Imho it's a pointless buzzword and best avoided.

Comment: See this excellent article about how poorly defined terms can cause you to have ultimately pointless debates. If you want to debate about the physics of the brain, and how the mind works, then do that - but trying to connect it to an emotionally charged buzzword just scrambles our thought process https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/WBdvyyHLdxZSAMmoz/taboo-your-words

Answer (score 4):

I don't really think it can ever be tested. Personally what convinces me there is no free will is the large amount of evidence that the chemistry of the brain determines our moods, even our personality. Some substances change our mood and behaviour. [Brain trauma or surgery can change a personality beyond recognition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phineas_Gage). Electrodes in the brain can provoke emotions undifferentiated from genuine ones. And patients who are unaware of the mind alteration they are subjected to usually attribute their own thought and behaviour to themselves, going as far as inventing a personal reason for waving their hand when it is in fact the surgeon that made them wave it.

I could be convinced there is free will by the evidence that there are thoughts and actions that can't be explained by biochemistry, with the caveat that we would have to first rule out the gap between observation and theory is not due to a flaw of our theory, which is probably impossible. Note that it would not erase the massive amount of evidence that biochemistry at least influences most of what we do or think, so free will is already very limited.

This problem is similar to that of the creationist gap argument, according to which since we can't explain the beginning of the universe it must have been created: to come to this conclusion, we first would need to establish that our scientific knowledge is perfect, and it is obviously not.

Even a time machine wouldn't be enough. There are different definitions for free will, but in the end what they have in common (except notably for compatibilist free will, which is not really free anyway) is the idea that under the same circumstances, things could have gone a different way, other decisions could have been taken. If we could rewind time and observe the same situation to as if it has a different outcome, it would be an hint but only if we can rule out the possibility of randomness due to quantum effects. A proper study would have to fully understand this randomness and its probability distribution, then show that the same situation rewinded 1000 times did not match the previsions. And yet again, in that case I would suspect our understanding of the randomness first, so we are back to square one.

Comment: I agree. That was my point.

Comment: You first say "I don't really think it can ever be tested," then you say "I could be convinced there is free will by the evidence that there are thoughts and actions that can't be explained by biochemistry."  If you could be convinced by evidence, then isn't obtaining that evidence (or failing to) a test?

Comment: After this I explain why what could convince me will probably never be available. If nothing could convince me, it would say more about my dogmatism than about the problem.

Comment: That's quite a different thing to say, than that a test is logically impossible.

Comment: No, it's the same. The test is in fact logically impossible, and I explain why.

Comment: If empirical evidence can convince you of the truth of something, then by definition an empirical test of that thing is logically possible.  In addition you are actually asserting that an empirical test *has already* been done, via our discoveries in neuroscience, answering in the negative (probably no free will).

Comment: It is not because something would convince me that it is possible to produce it. If Jesus appeared to me like he appeared to saint Paul, I would be convinced of his divinity by this miracle, but nobody can make it happen. The hints to determinism I give in my answer do not rule out free will, just limit it strongly (as in "**probably** no free will").

Comment: OK but that's not "logically impossible," that's "practically impossible."  It's not logically impossible for Jesus to appear like that, just practically impossible.

Comment: The idea that no experiment can prove free will "once and for all" is a good indication of free will. The material impossibility of precisely reproducing the "the same" experimental conditions is implicitly compared here with the scientific protocol that "in theory" we could eliminate or reduce such indeterminacies. In such dichotomies, I believe, lurks an assumption of free will. I'm enough of a pragmatist to think "common sense" assumptions of free constitute very compelling evidence.

Comment: @Nelson Alexander: assumption of anything will never be evidence, let alone compelling. I must admit i fail to follow your logic.

Comment: @causative: you are hairspliting at this point. There is no contradiction with thinking it cannot ever be done. I don't think i can ever jump over to the Moon, is it logically impossible or practicaly impossible ? Who cares ? It's impossble anyway. I would also argue that proving the completeness of our scientific knowledge is foremost a logic problem, because it requires proving no exception can ever be found (black swan problem).

Comment: No, this is the heart of the matter.  If you think X is false, even if you're highly confident, that does not mean it is logically impossible to test X.  The point of the test is that you may still be wrong despite your confidence.  The question is whether free will is an empirical question at all, not whether you think we have it.

Comment: @armand. Yeah, my comment is a little buggy. I'm basically thinking of Kant's notion that free will is a necessary assumption of reasoning itself. He attempts to deduce such "assumptions" from the givens of experience. We know that science only operates with assumptions that cannot in turn be proven by science. I was not adducing the "assumption" of free will as evidence. The "evidence" lies in the broad consensus or mutual "common sense" of assuming free will. I suspect the idea of an "experiment" proving no free will is internally incoherent, but I need to clarify this better.

Comment: @causative: the completeness of scientific knowledge is a logic problem related to the nature of inductive reasoning. Proving that our understanding of biochemistry is perfect and that variations from the model are due to free will is an impossible - not impractical - impossible task. So yeah, free will can't be tested. Yet can I imagine something that would make me change my mind ? Yes. It's just impossible to produce.

Comment: "Kant's notion that free will is a necessary assumption of reasoning itself." Even Kant can say stupid stuff. He is excused, as a XVIII century man he had a poor knowledge of neurology. Why on earth would it be impossible to reason without free will ? Spinoza who didn't believe in free will had no problem reasoning, so just saying "Kant said so" won't be very convincing.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a question about philosophy of science. I'm surprised nobody has mentioned the criteria of falsifiability.

Simply put, for a hypothesis to even be suitable to be proven or disproven through scientific inquiry, it has to be falsifiable: it has to be conceivable that contradictory evidence could be observed, or reasoned from observation? The hypothesis that "All swans are white" is falsifiable, regardless of whether it is true or not. The hypothesis that "All solids have a melting point" is not falsifiable, because it is not possible to observe that a particular solid *does not have* a melting point, only that it has not reached a melting point.

So, let's look at your question, which, from your two formulations of it, I paraphrase as "Is it possible for us to prove whether or not we possess free will?"

"Possess" is vague, but what you're actually asking, is, "Are either the hypothesis 'We are capable of acting out of free will' or the hypothesis 'We are incapable of acting out of free will' falsifiable?"

The answer to this would then hinge on whether or not an action was precipitated by free will being something that can be observed, or, be deductively reasoned from observable phenomena.

Right at the outset, you can't conclusively prove a negative, so "We are capable of acting out of free will" is not falsifiable — to falsify it, you'd have to observe that we are *never* capable of acting out of free will. So that is not a valid hypothesis for scientific inquiry.

So, is "We are incapable of acting out of free will" falsifiable? Could we observe an example of a human acting out of free will?

Interestingly, Karl Popper, who first defined the notion of falsifiability, specifically addressed something very close to this question: whether the statement "We are incapable of acting out of altruism" is falsifiable. Quoting from the [footnotes of the wikipedia page "Falsifiability"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability#cite_note-allactionsareegotisticnotfalsifiable-60):

> "This theory ['All human actions are egotistic, motivated by
> self-interest'] is widely held: it has variants in behaviourism,
> psychoanalysis, individual psychology, utilitarianism, vulgar-marxism,
> religion, and sociology of knowledge. Clearly this theory, with all
> its variants, is not falsifiable: no example of an altruistic action
> can refute the view that there was an egotistic motive hidden behind"

*(Popper, Karl (1983). Bartley, III (ed.).Realism and the Aim of Science: From the Postscript to The Logic of Scientific Discovery.)*

So, for Popper, the answer to your question seems pretty simple: no. To his view, behavioral motivation is strictly unknowable, therefore questions about it are not falsifiable, therefore they cannot be proven or disproven. If you're ok with an appeal to authority, there's an answer for you.

Obviously, though, we can ask whether Popper's statement "no example of an altruistic action can refute the view that there was an egotistic motive hidden behind" is falsifiable (and I'm sure he thought hard about that, and was content that it wasn't." Would it be possible for someone to make a direct observation, or provided deduction from direct observation, that proved an action to be purely altruistic and not motivated by selfishness? Let's be careful here: the answer, to the best of my knowledge, is "I sure can't think of one". That doesn't mean there isn't one. We can't be sure.

So, I personally suspect Popper was doing what scientists often do: speaking in a manner that sounds definitive, but taking it as read that the listener understands that *science doesn't describe reality* or provide fact (even though the listener very often doesn't.) Science provides the best predictive model possible given the available information. That's all.

If I can digress: you hear some very ignorant people nowadays in the course of current events describing science as "just another religion". That's wrong in a lot of ways, but chief among them is that very misunderstanding. Scientists may state things in a manner that sounds like they consider what they're stating facts, but privately they know they're talking about *likelihood*, a model, not *truth*. They know that new evidence can upend the whole model tomorrow. The map isn't the territory. I think this concept gets lost in the popular mind. (Although it's important to say, a lot of people who do understand it then go on to make the converse mistake of trying to downplay the practical veracity of empirical scientific conclusions with statements like "It's all just theories". There's a slight misconception there, too, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.)

This is an important digression because it provides the correct answer to your question.

I know you were hoping for an argument concluding with "yes" or a "no", but the correct answer, based on current best-available evidence, is "it's unlikely."

Comment: Popper sidestepped the question of neuro-transmitters and in-brain rewards - or subjectively: The good feeling we create for ourselves by helping others. Some people don't have these, at least apparently, and derive no pleasure from altruism. The real question is: How do I define "selfless"? If I have no actual benefit from my action, but it makes me feel good, is that still selfless?

Answer (score 3):

Although I believe we have free will, it is actually impossible to ever prove it via any test whatsoever, because you cannot prove that the test results are meaningful at all. In particular, you cannot rely on randomization in the test because you have no proof that there is true randomness in reality, and so the test results may be deterministic, in which case you cannot provably exclude the possibility that even the test itself (the design and the execution) was just predetermined.

Ultimately the point is simply that **if** reality is deterministic, and we are stuck inside it, **then** everything we do is deterministic too, and so how can we possibly test for freedom of choice when we cannot even have freedom in testing?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the second paragraph? Are you saying that in a deterministic world no tests about anything are possible, or just test about free will be pointless? Naively thinking, in a deterministic universe, you are determined to run a test for free will, and the (pre-determined) results would indicate that free will does not exists. There is no contradiction in that scenario. What am I missing?

Comment: @user000001: In a purely deterministic world, we have no freedom in choosing tests. What if you were programmed to only perform certain tests under certain conditions rather than under conditions that would be needed for the tests to be meaningful? And if you were programmed to come to a certain conclusion, what is the meaning of any test you perform? Just because something is consistent does not mean it is true. In a deterministic universe you may be programmed to do some so-called 'free will test' and be programmed to conclude that free will exists. Also no contradiction.

Comment: But the lack of free will doesn't mean that there is a malicious actor that determined everything, just that the decision algorithm uses only external inputs and internal state, and no non-material "free-will" or "god's-will" input variable exists. You imply that the existence of this non-material input would make the results of scientific tests more accurate, but there is no evidence that a) it actually exists, b) if it existed it would improve the accuracy. I would argue that it would make things worse, since by definition the input would not be based on reality, so it would be noise.

Comment: @user000001: I didn't say anything about malice. I said that you cannot prove anything...... You failed to address my objection to your point, namely that there is no contradiction in the case that you are programmed to conclude that free will exists. Let me emphasize again, consistency does not imply truth. This is a basic fact. So whether a hypothesis is consistent or not does not provide any evidence that it is true.

Comment: If you conclude that it exists when it really doesn't, then obviously the test was flawed. My original question in the first comment, that you still haven't answered, is why do you think that free will reduces the chances of flawed tests? The argument that you aren't "free" to choose the right tests to do is really bogus, because you can make choices just fine without free will, just look at all the classification/decision support algorithms that exist out there.

Comment: @user000001: Ah I see now; you completely misunderstood the argument. I never claimed that free will reduces the chance of flawed tests. However, I stated clearly that one cannot **prove** existence of free will via any tests *because* tests for freedom in a deterministic world are meaningless. As for your last sentence, it doesn't make sense because we're talking about **freedom** of choice, not simply choice.

Comment: The point is, a test cannot be meaningful if we cannot have any guarantee at all about the usefulness of the test results. And since we have no guarantee that we have not been programmed to do certain tests and get certain results and make certain conclusions, we cannot obtain any guarantee on the usefulness of any purported test for free will. Note that even if you make a true conclusion from a meaningless test, it does not make the test meaningful, just as a stopped clock is right twice a day.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand better what you are trying to say, but still I am not  convinced by this line of thought. You use the word "programmed" as if there was some agent that carefully designed the initial conditions in order to trick us. Whereas if you understand determinism as the evolution of a dynamic system, that scenario seems extremely unlikely (think chaos theory).  In general there can be no 100% guarantee about anything being correct (with or without free will), but that doesn't mean that we can't have good confidence that properly designed experiments are generally reliable.

Comment: Thank you for the conversation though, it was very inspiring, maybe I'll ask a new question about this at some point :)

Comment: @user000001: The problem is that you are still confused between consistency and truth. I never claimed that we *are* programmed to be tricked. I only stated the fact that we **cannot** exclude that possibility, and so all our tests become meaningless. Notice that you cannot talk about likelihood in a fully deterministic setting, which is precisely why no test can prove anything in a fully deterministic world. Neither can you have any sort of confidence bound based on statistics if statistics do not apply! That is really the point here; you are relying on unstated assumptions.

Comment: In any case, feel free to ask more, or continue in chat when the option is presented. =)

Answer (score 3):

From the Kant perspective, freedom is wanting what is necessary and unavoidable. From that position, an agent have the free will, if his actions are consistence with his intentions. This definition is independent from to which extend are those intentions determined or predictable.

You can disagree with that definition as far as you will, but doing so, you'd have to connect free will with the ability to act against the intentions (either because internal or external hurdles) which is quite the opposite of which people normally define as freedom.

Being predictable or determined is not contrary to the free will. If I let you choose between landing in a 5 star holiday resort, or North Korean concentration camp, I can quite assume your decision is both predictable and determined, and nevertheless, is the expression of what you'll call your free will.

Comment: This answer is interesting, but Kant's definition of free will doesn't seem really compelling in the age of computer programs. Under this definition, it seems that all bots that act according to some internal objectives, are programmed to have "free" will, but most people arguing for free will would not accept that their freedom is exactly the same as that of a bot.

Comment: This is simply redefining free will into something that we know exists. It is not what people usually mean by "free will", which is libertarian free will, the idea that one could have chosen to act otherwise than happened.

Comment: @armand, "free will" as "libertarian" how you define it here is not necessarily like most people think of it, but sooner a specifically North American's tradition of philosophy.

Comment: No. Even if it was not labeled "libertarian" at the time, Thomas Aquinas already held to the idea that our minds are free from causality, because otherwise the notion of sin would be nonsense. The debate was also live among the Hellenistic tradition of philosophy. Thomas Aquinas, Epicurus and Aristotle are *not* from the North American tradition of philosophy... (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_will_in_antiquity)

Comment: That is true. But my point was of a different sense (at least, as I intended it). You sounded in your comment like you are giving the only or the principal understanding of free will. I just wanted to say there are other ways, too. @Danubian's answer, btw, is worthwile, - to other people then yourself.

Comment: Redefining free will as something that is nor free, nor about will is just a coping mechanism for people who have cognitive dissonance, intellectually understanding that we are just as determined as the falling rocks, but unable to do the leap to admit the conclusion, or for religious reasons desperately need something to put the label "free will" on.

Comment: @user000001 That's actually not correct. Free will means two things in Kant's work: Firstly, the ability to give one's own will rules/laws (autonomy), and secondly, to be able to transgress these laws (freedom of choice). With one of these things missing, the will is either determined from the outside (heteronomous) or not free in a meaningful sense (his example in the Groundwork is God who cannot but act good).

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking: Thanks for the clarification, my comment was based entirely on the text of the answer above. About the transgression requirement, it seems that would rule out simple if-then-else bots, but in some sense neural nets could potentially satisfy it, since they create new rules in a non-deterministic way.

Answer (score 2):

Preface:  I don't think we have free will.  Or we only have it in a compatibilist sense.  However:

First, consider a possible picture of "free will."  In this picture, the universe might be compared to a video game where brains are controlled by external "players."  The video game has its own internal logic, which we call the laws of physics, and the external players don't operate according to that logic.  The external players might operate according to their own logic, which we set aside from the laws of the game and call "free will."  I don't think this picture is accurate - I don't think there are external players - but that's a picture of how it could be.  And in theory it could be possible to test for the accuracy of that picture.

So we could determine if there is free will according to this picture by first fully understanding the laws of physics for all non-brain objects - including any randomness inherent in those laws of physics.  With powerful enough sensors and computers, we could use that to run a physically perfect simulation of the brain, giving physical error bounds on any randomness.  If the brain consistently behaves outside the error bounds, that would be evidence that there is some external controlling factor not accounted for by our theory of physics, which is by hypothesis perfect on every non-brain object.  And we could call that factor "free will."

Anyway I don't think it's likely we would find any such thing.  It wouldn't be simple or elegant to have special laws of physics that are only for brains; it would violate Occam's razor.

It would also not mean that the external players have free will in their own external universe - they may have their own rules in their external universe that still dictate their behavior.

Comment: I dont think we can probe that scenario for free will. After all the characters (avatar) of the game will forcefully operate under the game rules (physics), even if the gamers themself had free will. So for example the characters in the game will not be able to do things that are not permitted by the game rules. All the reasoning of this sort become recursive at certain points.

Comment: The avatar is controlled by the player, which makes it behave in a way not strictly dictated by the internal laws of the game that apply to all other objects.  For instance in Mario Kart you press different keys to make your character move - nothing totally contained within the game says the character must move to the left, that's your input causing it.

Comment: I dont think this latest case apply to our universe. Is the e quivalent to say that jesus walked on the waters and resuscitate corpse so he had free will because he trascended the rules of the game. But that certainly was not the case. Also, by definition, if someone is able to do a thing in a universe, that thing *must* be permitted by the rules.

Comment: You don't get it, it's not about walking on water.  It's about making your character take the mundane action you want it to, when nothing in the game rules say it must take that particular action.

Comment: Look, the game says you *can* control your character - you aren't breaking the rules in that sense.  But you are doing something that causes something in the game to behave in a way that the internal laws of the game do not fully dictate.

Comment: Againt, that is an edge scenario that certainly does not apply to our universe. Try to thing at practical examples of your scenario, applied to our universe...then you will see contradiction arising all round.

Comment: @Yamar69 - Isn't the scenario described by causative in the 2nd paragraph just something like the interactive dualism of Descartes, where the body (and much of the brain) obeys the laws of physics, but the brain takes input from something outside the laws of physics, namely the soul? Similarly a game takes inputs from a player whose behavior is not generated by the laws of the gameworld. And note the experiment in the 3rd paragraph could potentially disprove this notion of free will by showing the brain's output is entirely generated by the laws of physics, no need for a special "soul" input.

Comment: The reliability of the brain model is a big issue. It is perfect in your hypothesis, but how would we many sure of it practically? Usually we vet models by comparing their predictions with the behavior of what they model: if it matches all the time the model is perfect. So in our case, if the brain and its model didn't match, I would suspect the model is flawed, rather than the effect of free will.

Comment: ^That. To run your experiment, you had to accept your hypothetical perfect model is possibly incapable of modeling the brain, which in turn assumes the world is non-materialist. On the other hand, if you assume the world is purely materialist, any mismatch in the model is simply proof your model is flawed. Furthermore, in the materialist world, incapability to produce a perfect model is only indicative of our incompetence and not non-materialism.

Comment: No, the point is that the model is tested and validated as perfect on *all nonbrain objects*.  Then if it does not work on the brain that would be evidence something special is happening in the brain that is not happening in any other object.

Comment: And how do you validate it as perfect ? Science is no magic and inductive reasoning can't guarantee your model is perfect, only that it worked so far. Then when it stops working on brains it leaves you with the possibility that your understanding of the brain is flawed and you can't prove anything.

Comment: If you have a single scanning and simulation system that has worked on a million other objects - that does not rely on any particular human understanding of the object, that simply scans the atoms in the object and predicts the result, and does so perfectly as far as anyone can tell.  Then if it does not work on the brain, that would be strong evidence something weird is happening in the brain.

Answer (score 2):

**From physics Point of view**

Everything is just particles and forces. All emergent behaviour can be explained from the underlying laws. The brain is made of particles that interact via forces. So:

Imagine a closed of environment (test room) with a human test subject. Now say we take a snapshot of the whole setup (test room and test subject) down to the finest granularity physics allows for so we have perfect information.

With a complete understanding of the laws of physics we can now (in principle) simulate the room and the test subject and compare to the actual behavior of the test subject. If free will does not exist, simulation and reality will be in accordance.

Note that this assumes that quantum effects can be neglected in the macroscopic workings of the brain. If not, these are just random anyway and is not an argument that free will can exist.

**From an evolutionary PoV**

We are placed somewhere in the tree of life. For those who think free will exist, they must place the introduction of it somewhere on the evolutionary tree and argue how *the breaking of the laws of physics can be introduced by changes in DNA*. This seems close to impossible to me.

Otherwise they must argue that all self-replicating molecules (or just molecules) contain a bit of free will. Both of these have absolutely no evidence, so I don't see why we should pursue the issue since there is no indication of free will other than the illusion of it, which some people just can't take for an answer.

Comment: I dont think is possible to just simulate a room...you will need to simulate the entire universe that contains that room in order to do so...which is practically impossible.

Comment: Natural _laws_ (like any theories) exist exceptionally thanks to human good will for them. A natural law is homologous to an individual's _ends_. (The difference that one is mechanic and the other is teleologic is simply due to seeing time as moving from past to future, or from future to past - and is not important). Natural laws are "inverted" copycats of human ends; but the latter assume free will.

Comment: @ttnphns, Let's not unneccesarily complicate things here. I'm talking about natural (physical) laws that exist no matter whether humans are around to describe and label them as this or that, or not. I'm not really seeing what your point is with regards to the experiment.

Comment: @Yamar69, If we try to be practical: maybe a short term experiment would be possible if small fluctuations only make small variance in outcome of our behavior (i.e., is non-chaotic), we could get a good enough model for the behavior if we put up some allowance for error (as in any practical scientific experiment) and repeat the experiment over and over to average out the "noise".

Comment: @SupAI that will leave quantum entanglement and other know physics facts completely out of the games. From our current scientific knowledge i dont really think is possible to construct a reliable experiment in that way. By a purely tought experiment i definetly get what you are saying...altough i dont think is relevant if is not appliable to our own universe.

Comment: @Yamar69, To answer your question with your own assumptions: It is impossible to prove any theory in science. Any experiment will always just strengthen, but never prove, a theory. We can thus, potentially, get good evidence for the non-existence of free will if we apply the scientific method on the hypothesis. 
When it comes to proving anything with pure logic, we always starts with the axioms - which we can not obtain for our universe (not with certainty at least).

Comment: It seems that in first line you are assuming what you are trying to prove, and in the "simulation" you are violating or at least idealizing the physical laws you deem the sole explanatory context. But can't we simplify your experiment? All we need is a relatively sealed, consistent chamber in which we place 1,000 subjects one by one. Perhaps all the same gender and age, though the is really unnecessary. If behavior demonstrates will and will is externally determined by some "force," won't they behave identically? If the variations due to body, memory, etc. are specific to individuals....

Comment: ...then you need a different causal "force" and explanation for each individual. If the behavioral outcomes in your physically invariable chamber vary widely, it would seem you have have failed to demonstrate the sort of explanation allowable in physics. Or you are forced into an infinite regress of causes. If we appear to make free choices and it is commonly believed that we make choices, then I'd say the burden of proof falls on the determinists to hypothesize an external causation and demonstrate perfectly predictable subjects.

Comment: About the "room experiment", the problem always remains: how do we know our understanding of physics is perfect ?

Comment: @armand, I don't think it's possible to prove anything with certainty (i.e., know that our understanding is perfect). But the question OP asked was whether we could come up with an experiment to 'prove' free will. With regards to experiments, they don't prove anything, just strengthen the evidence (or refutes a theory), so I assume that's what's meant by 'proving'.

Answer (score 2):

First, let us define our terms. Assuming that by "free will" we mean acting in a manner that is not pre-determined, where somewhere inside our mind, an actual decision is being made that is not a simple causal chain. We will leave the details of how the mind works open, but we state that free will is proven if a being can make a decision that with infinite knowledge and processing power of the physical reality outside his mind could not be predicted.

The problem we need to solve is that our mind has an elaborate construction of agency that science has already disproven. There've been a number of experiments showing that fast actions can be measured in the brain quicker than consciousness can possibly work (according to our current knowledge), but the test persons report making a decision. Our current working model is that the brain acts and our consciousness then makes up a story of how it decided to act. This is not always true, however, as we can sit an deliberate on a course of action, obviously.

Our experiment would have to circumvent this illusion, and that means we cannot be judges of our own free will. Our mind will tell us that we acted intentionally, even when we clearly didn't, so it cannot be trusted on this question.

However, we also cannot judge from outside, as a) our infinite prediction machine doesn't include the mind itself and b) we hand-waived how exactly the mind works, so we have no way to measure it.

Under these conditions, it is impossible to devise such an experiment. We need a much better understanding of how the mind works before we can tackle the question of free will. Specifically, we must understand how decision processes work and which parts are deterministic and which parts are not and how that indeterminism works. If I speak of "conscious decision", what does that mean? Where does that consciousness reside and how does it make decisions?

Marvin Minski famously claimed that the mind is simply a hugely complex machine made of simple agents. No individual part is intelligent, intelligence is an emergent property. If that is the case then we will not find consciousness as the phenomenon we are looking for disappears under the microscope the way culture or fashion trends disappear when you examine a single painting or dress.

At the current state of our knowledge, we cannot imagine such an experiment because we do not know enough about the subject matter in question. "Free will" is a philosophical construct more than a scientific one.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers mentioned, we should first define free will.

I suggest the following definition, which is not perfect though because it can be explained by other phenomena instead of free will.

Let put the question this way:

Are there systems in the universe whose evolution is not predictable (from within the universe) neither with deterministic, nor with probabilistic (Bayesian) laws?

The answer is **yes**. Thomas Breuer [has shown mathematically](https://homepages.fhv.at/tb/tb/cms/index.html%3Fdownload=tbDISS.pdf) that from the point of view of any given in-universe observer, the behavior of a system in which he is properly included, is unpredictable with any deterministic or probabilistic laws.

Now, does this necessarily certify the existence of free will? Actually it only certifies the existence of events without physical (measurable from within the universe) cause and that such events necessarily happen in any system which properly includes the observer himself (from his point of view).

Are there alternative explanations of this result besides free will? Yes. There are.

- Out-of-universe events affecting the physical world. This may be divine intervention, input ports, computer player for whom this world is a game, etc. But since the theorem would still work in the wider universe that includes those beings, we still will face the same question (for instance, we could conclude that God has free will and intervenes in the behavior of the observer, like player intervenes in the behavior of player-controlled character).
- Initial conditions of the universe affect events at present and in the future. In a sense, initial conditions are also a kind of input from outside the universe. And again, if our universe is a part of a greater world, the theorem will still apply to it. This rises the question, who and how set up the very first initial conditions? Was it a manifestation of some kind of free will of that being?

There are other questions that arise.

- Is free will somehow connected with intellect? Yes, the observer finds himself unpredictable, but the theorem does not require an intelligent observer, it will work with a computer, for instance. Does our definition of free will require that the observer could affect universe in a way he desires rather than just physically unpredictable?
- Is the existence of qualia needed for free will? What about states of the observer when he does not have qualia (unconscious or before formation of brain)? Does he have free will at those moments?

So, the questions still remain.

Comment: Free will can't be reduced to unpredictability, at least not while keeping its utility as a concept. It might be true that some events are purely random and unpredictable, but if we don't also demonstrate that there is a mind who controls the outcome of this event, and this mind is both agent and patient of the outcome (God puppeteering me doesn't count, it must be me puppeteering me) it's not free will. More precisely, we'd have the "free", but not the "will".

Comment: @armand random events are Bayesian, thus probabilistically predictable. Breuer showed that there are probabilistically unpredictable events, those events are not "random" (neither they are deterministic). Peter van Inwagen had shown that neither random nor determinist universe is compatible with free will.

Comment: this does not address my point. Even if some events are unpredictable, they must also be the result of a decision in order for there to be free will, and my decisions have to come from me. This point you totally ignored in your response, to fully concentrate on unpredictability. But unpredictability is not free will. Of course you can define the concept of free will as you please, but if this concept becomes void and totally interchangeable with another, what is the point?

Comment: There's some research where they tried to illustrate what would be involved in reverse-engineering an organism, by reverse engineering a microchip. It turns out to be incredibly, gigantically, difficult..

Answer (score 2):

There are three broad categories of stance on free will: libertarian free will, no free will, and compatibilism.

Libertarian free will is generally a religious stance, premised on substance dualism - a supervenient but seperate layer, can generate 'acts of will' independent of the material world (eg, manifesting from our soul).

Those who deny free will, argue from our understanding of material causation, to say there can be no sources of causation that aren't material, so the sense we have of originating causes through deliberating, ie acts of will, must be an illusion. Notably, proponents of this view generally think that everyone arguing for free will is arguing for libertarian free will.

Compatibilism, the large majority view of professional philosophers, is the view that freedom of will is *subjectively* real, but operates through material causation. In the same way, identity is not pictured as the 'inextensible' realm like Descartes thought, information has material reality, even when considering substrate independence (and Turing completeness). It is *useful* to define conventional notions about identity, even accepting they are fundamentally reducible to atoms. The behaviour of atoms is a poor way to predict the behaviour of others, so we form a heuristic or explanatory layer, with identities in, in which human motivations are pictured as causal, from a supervenient layer.

To those who deny free will, this is seen as like the libertarian free will stance. But it is more like asserting biology has useful conceptual units and narrative groupings, even after accepting that the fundamental rules of the units involved are defined by physics. Identity, and will, and intentions, are useful narrative groupings, which allow us to better predict other humans, than knowing their  position and momentum.

For a compatibilist, no test could 'prove' free will is not reducible to the behaviour of atoms, because they don't claim this. Asking for proof of free will in this view, is like asking for proof that cells exist - it just is a useful grouping, in it's own layer of explanation. Dunbar's number points to the neocortex as having evolved specifically to predict other humans, so we can go further to show how it is socially adaptive to understand intentions of ourselves & others, & this has substantially contributed to human cognitive & social complexity.

Comment: Maybe you should make more explicit what your clarification of how free will can be understood means for its testifiability in particular.

Answer (score 1):

We would need an experiment with a result that is either possible with free will and impossible without free will or vice versa. (Better yet would be an experiment that forces such a result).

I think anything I could possibly do with free will I could do (be forced to do) without free will. There’s the possibility that there are things that I couldn’t do out of my free will but could do without free will. But then I never heard anyone claiming that Harold Shipman only could kill 200 people because it wasn’t his free will, so it is hard to say what exactly would be impossible if I had free will.

Answer (score 0):

Free will is the ability to *decide* one's own actions.

This is easily tested. You just have to decide to do something and see, if your body obeys your decision.

Some people may claim that it is not necessarily you who decides your actions, but they have no idea about *who else* could it be.

Comment: Most current (well, like in the last 200 years or so?) philosophers question those narratives of self-evident agency as naive. The question is not *who else* but *why **someone** in the first place*. Also, the question is about *proof/test*, which is a technicality and cannot be answered by appeal to self-evidence. This is why we prefer to base answers on texts of philosophers instead of personal opinions.

Comment: I can see nothing naive about observing the results of deliberate decisions and concluding that there must be someone who made the decisions. Someone decided that you should write this comment, someone chose the words, someone determined the whole thing. Your comment was not a random collection of random letters, there was intent and intelligence behind. Someone wanted to send me this message for the purpose of educating me.

Comment: If you think this is without problems, you should probably read Descartes. One of the philosophically stronger and more recent opponents of the classical reality (not the illusion/impression) of free will is Daniel Dennett.

Comment: My unfree will forced me to decide to do something and that’s what my body did. Usually we go further: My unfree will forced me to change my mind at the last second.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a rigorous answer, but I find that this [video](https://youtu.be/9uRTjfhIf4M?t=698) is quite revealing about free will.

This was a scientific experiment done on a patient with epilepsy that uncovered the nature of free will. The part of this video containing the experiment runs from 11:38 to 17:50, and if you want, you can watch the rest of the video, it is really interesting. I love this video series and it's where all the big questions try to get answered, and I highly recommend it. Enjoy!

---

**EDIT:**

**Summary of the video:** There is an experiment done on a patient where they play a game where they try to mirror each other's moves (the patient and the other person who plays the game with them). If one of them predicts the other's move, then they win that round. There are electrodes planted on the patient's brain (due to brain surgery) and they collect and process the brain patterns to predict what move the patient will do next. As it turns out, when the patient makes a move, it was predicted beforehand about 300 milliseconds before the patient had done the move. Therefore, the patient did not consciously decide the move but rather it was made for them by their subconscious. The experimenter then concludes that free will is an illusion that we are not in control of.

This was a free-will experiment that reveals the nature of free will and it confirms that free will can be tested objectively.

This means that agents in the universe can, in fact, determine if they have free will by conducting an experiment like this one. Free will is not anymore a debate and intellectual challenge, but rather it can be experimentally verified.

I am not familiar with the halting problem and I have not put any thought into it, so it is something I cannot answer.

Comment: It seems like you haven't made an answer, you have pointed to a video. You should summarise what you see as it's argument, and link it directly to the particulars of the question as asked above.

Comment: @CriglCragl I edited my question, please have a look. I answered the first 2 questions of the OP's question, but the halting problem is something I cannot answer.

Comment: What you list is accounted for by the multi-agent nature of our minds (confirmed by split-brain research), with conscious awareness as the global workspace.

Comment: @CriglCragl But doesn't that prove that you can test free will? And do all agents of the mind have equal free will? Or is there a disproportionate amount of free will of the agents? Maybe agents controlling other agents, thereby restricting the other agent's free will. Even asking which agent is the real you is difficult and then saying that agent is capable of expressing free will is key, I think, to finding the truth about the idea.

Comment: All good points. For me it's a generalisation of how neurons can take multiple signals and fire at a certain total threshold, and this allows their tuned dynamic networks to embody learning (neural networks). I've posted my answer, that I don't see it as testable, so that's my bias here..

Answer (score -2):

In principle, yes, it could be possible in future to prove the existence of free will. If we have free will, then our actions must be governed by something else in addition to the laws of physics. It might eventually be possible to study a living brain and body in sufficiently close detail to observe the necessary violation of physical laws. Note, however, that such an experiment could never *disprove* free will — you might just be unable to look closely enough.